# Is there a way to mirror the left n/8ths "block element" with unicode?

Tags: unicode

I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_Elements) that Unicode has these characters: Left one eighth, Left one fourth, left three eighths, etc... (U+2588 through U+258F)

```
▏▎▍▌▋▊▉
```

It doesn't seem to contain the "right" equivalent of those.  Is there some trick to displaying blocks with the right-half filled?

Comment: The systems that had these characters (from which Unicode imports them as legacy) typically also offered reverse video. In modern systems, that comes down to using a monospace font and swapping the foreground and background color yourself.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That sounds like an answer.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Thanks. Unfortunately, with the font my terminal uses, the block doesn't take up the full height, so it ends up with a weird top/bottom border when used.

Answer (score 3):

The right blocks are defined as of Unicode 13.0 released March 10, 2020.
They may display below depending on browser font:

```
U+2590 ▐ RIGHT HALF BLOCK
U+2595 ▕ RIGHT ONE EIGHTH BLOCK
U+1FB87  RIGHT ONE QUARTER BLOCK
U+1FB88  RIGHT THREE EIGHTHS BLOCK
U+1FB89  RIGHT FIVE EIGHTHS BLOCK
U+1FB8A  RIGHT THREE QUARTERS BLOCK
U+1FB8B  RIGHT SEVEN EIGHTHS BLOCK
```

References:

- https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-3.2/U32-2580.pdf
- https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/Unicode-13.0/U130-1FB00.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, the 0x1f* ones don't work with the font I was using, but this is the correct answer so I've marked it such.